# Calling a specific endpoint on a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a really nube question and therefore both apologize in advance and stand ready to accept anyone's ire thereto..
However.. 
Here's my controller:

```
namespace DMV_BE.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
{


    //returns serialized json
    public JsonResult Index()
    {
        //  List<DMV_BE.Models.DMVResultModel> list = new List<Models.DMVResultModel>();

        DMVResultModel r = new DMVResultModel();
        ModelHelper mh = new ModelHelper();
        mh.fillDMVResult(r);

        return Json(r, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }


    public JsonResult QuerySelf()
    {
    //  List<DMV_BE.Models.DMVResultModel> list = new List<Models.DMVResultModel>();

        DMVResultModel r = new DMVResultModel();
        ModelHelper mh = new ModelHelper();
        mh.fillDMVResult(r);

        return Json(r, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }




    public JsonResult QueryOthers()
    {
    //  List<DMV_BE.Models.DMVResultModel> list = new List<Models.DMVResultModel>();

        DMVResultModel r = new DMVResultModel();
        ModelHelper mh = new ModelHelper();
        mh.fillDMVResult(r);

        return Json(r, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and now I need to call QuerySelf and QueryOthers endpoint from a browser....I invariably plug `http://localhost:56928/QuerySelf` into chrome, which invariably goes to a 404 type page.  Can anyone please help me out?

Thank You!

Comment: assuming your site is running on localhost port 56928, use:  `http://localhost:56928/Home/QuerySelf`.  format is:  protocol://host:port/controller/method

Comment: If you need to you can also define via `HttpRoute` if you decide your convention is not ideal.  But otherwise Sam's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Actually both of your actions (QuerySelf and QueryOthers) are returning JsonResult, which is not supposed to display something on the web page...

Try [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to test these methods or create an ajax call and log the response like below...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Home/QuerySelf",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```